# CSS issue only in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am using a spring based application where all the images are loaded from a separate image server. I have a common css file used accross the application. Initially it had doctype as MATHML and i tried other doctypes also. But the css is not loaded only for IE9 browser mode with IE9 standards but it works for IE9 browser mode with IE8 document standards. And the same is working for firefox, chrome, IE8. Can anyone suggest me the solution to make it work in IE9.

I have tried using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

but still it did not work.

Comment: Did you try `content="IE=8"` or something in that style?

Comment: check it with `content="IE=9"`

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, with the info in your question we can only guess at the answer. Tell us about how you're loading the CSS (perhaps show some code), tell us what different setups you've tried and why you thought they work (and why/how they didn't help), tell us what you see when observing network traffic, etc. etc.

Comment: Just a wild guess.. but is the website on http and the css on https? More details would be handy to provide a solution..